# Determine the interpolation polynomial $p_n\in \Pi_n$

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

Determine to $n=0, \ldots  , 6$ the interpolation polynomial $p_n\in \Pi_n$ of order $n$ with the property $$p_n(k)=1+k+k^2, \ \ k=0, \ldots , n$$

So do we have to find the general formula of the polynonmial with the above property?

Comment: Only the7 first polynomials.

Comment: So do we have to find $p_0(x), \ p_1(x), \ p_2(x), \ p_3(x), \ p_4(x), \ p_5(x), \ p_6(x)$ ? @TitoEliatron

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Ok! So we can choose which method we use, Newton or Lagrange, or not? @TitoEliatron

Comment: I think so. But observe that knowing $p_n(x)$, it is not difficoult to obtain (almost directly) $p_{n+1}$ (you're just adding interpolation points). So Lagrange may not be the best merhod.

Comment: I got stuck right now. Do we have to find a method that the next order of polynomial is defined by the previous one? @TitoEliatron

Comment: NO, it was just a HINT for doing your work easier.

Comment: What do you know of interpolating a polynomial if the degree of the interpolating polynomial is high enough?

Comment: The higher the degree the better approximation we get, or not? @LutzLehmann

Comment: That idea is dangerously wrong, as Runge explored at the turn of the 19th century. For the given task it is not strong enough, you should get $p_2(x)=p_3(x)=...=1+x+x^2$. In general you can get such convergence if the function is analytical and you restrict the interpolation points to a disk that has no singularity of the function close to it. See the Runge example $f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$ with its singularities at $x=\pm i$.

Comment: So you mean from one $n$ the polynomial is constant as for the formula? @LutzLehmann

Comment: Or have I understood your comment wrong? @LutzLehmann

Comment: Yes, the interpolation of a polynomial will return exactly the same polynomial if the number of interpolation points is larger than the degree. Which happens here for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: I got stuck right now. Why is the number of interpolation points larger than the degree for $n\geq 2$? @LutzLehmann

Comment: Because on the right side of your defining equation you take the function values of a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: I am confused right now about the given equation. Isn't this the formula for the given values for $k$ ? Or is this the formula of the polynomial? @LutzLehmann

Comment: You are given $p_n(k)=f(k)$ where $f(x)=1+x+x^2$. The interpolation process only knows this. That the function to interpolate could have other values than $f(x)$ at non-integer points does not matter.

Comment: So for order $n=0$ we have a constant interpolating polynomial with $p_0(0)=1$, therefore we get $p_0(x)=1$. For order $n=1$ we have the interpolating polynomial of the form $p_1(x)=ax+b$ with $p_1(0)=1$ and $p_1(1)=3$, therefore we get $p_1(x)=2x+1$. @LutzLehmann

Comment: For order $n=2$ we have the interpolating polynomial of the form $p_2(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ with $p_2(0)=1$, $p_2(1)=3$ and $p_2(2)=7$, therefore we get $p_2(x)=x^2+x+1$. For order $n=3$ we have the interpolating polynomial of the form $p_3(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ with $p_3(0)=1$, $p_3(1)=3$, $p_3(2)=7$ and $p_3(3)=13$, therefore we get $p_3(x)=x^2+x+1$. For order $n=4$ we have the interpolating polynomial of the form $p_4(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ with $p_4(0)=1$, $p_4(1)=3$, $p_4(2)=7$, $p_4(3)=13$ and $p_4(4)=21$, therefore we get $p_4(x)=x^2+1x+1$. 

@LutzLehmann

Comment: But I haven't really understood how you saw that for $n\geq 2$ we get the same polynomial. Could you explain that? Do we consider that we want to interpolate $f(x)=1+x+x^2$ which is of degree $2$ and so an interpolating polynomial with more points than the degree is equal to the function? @LutzLehmann

Comment: Yes, exactly that. The difference $p_n(x)-f(x)$ is then a polynomial of degree $n$ with $n+1$ roots.

Comment: So we consider the difference $d(x)=p_n(x)-f(x)$. We have that $d(x)=0$ for $x=0, \ldots , n$, which are $n+1$ roots and it is of degree $n$ if $n\geq 2$. As for the case $n<2$, we have that the degree of $d(x)$ is $2$ and there are at most $2$ roots and so $d(x)$ doesn't have to be constant. Have I understood that correctly? @LutzLehmann

Comment: Yes, that is the more detailed description of the situation.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much!! :-) @LutzLehmann